# GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Error when trying to use orbit controls with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a Sky Box with three.js and have created the cube and applied the textures however, I now need to import the camera controls. I first created the OrbitControls.js file (with the correct code inside) but when I try to use `let controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );` to add the controls I get the error `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` when trying to use orbit controls with three.js. I added a three.module.js file and found the code for it. added it to my HTML with `<script type="module" src="three.module.js"></script>` but I still get the aforementioned error.

Here is my JS and the script tags that get three.js:

```
<body>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="three.module.js"></script>
        <script type="module">
    import { OrbitControls } from "./OrbitControls.js"
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = []
      let texture_ft = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_ft.jpg");
      let texture_bk = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_bk.jpg");
      let texture_up = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_up.jpg");
      let texture_dn = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_dn.jpg");
      let texture_rt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_rt.jpg");
      let texture_lf = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("cocoa_lf.jpg");

      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_ft }));
      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_bk }));
      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_up }));
      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_dn }));
      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_rt }));
      material.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_lf }));
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;
    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
  animate();

    let controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: "_the aforementioned error_" means that there's no such file on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a file directory issue. When you use `src="three.module.js"` in your HTML file, you're telling the browser that both your `.html` and `three.module.js` files are in the same folder. You're probably going to have to modify the src so it actually points to where the JavaSript file is located:

- `src="../three.module.js"` this goes up one folder
- `src="./subfolder/three.module.js"` this goes into a subfolder

Just look at your folder structure, and try to point to the right location. Same thing with OrbitControls.